# Adjoining several lists into a single data structure

Tags: python, list

Using Python, I had two lists whose length is the same and each data inside is related to each other with the same order. Hence, I made a list of lists as follows:

```
a1=[0, 1, 1, 2]
a2=[o, x, o, o]
-> A=[(0,o), (1,x), (1,o), (2,o)]
```

Later, I found another list which I wanted to add as well:

```
a3=[0,0,1,1]
```

While I can adjoin the list by calling the previous lists a1 and a2, I was wondering if there is any other simple way of adjoining it only using A and a2 because it seemed arduous if there were a lot of lists already adjoined in this way; I want a method which can be expanded easily for future.

Also, if making a list of lists is not the best way in this case, I want to know what other structures I should use.

Comment: Are you willing to use a library like Pandas or NumPy?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've just started learning so I'd appreciate any solution possibly with its merits and drawbacks.

Comment: It is hard to tell if a list of lists (or actually tuples in this case) is the most helpful without knowing how the information is to be used.

Comment: @micsthepick I just wanted to gather the information into a single structure. I'm just solving a mathematical problem and learning programming, so it is just for convenience. I found that when the lists are just scattered around, it's confusing when I try to find a data corresponding to an element of a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with Pandas.  As all your lists have the same length, you can treat each list as a column in a Pandas DataFrame.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd

a1 = [0, 1, 1, 2]
a2 = [o, x, o, o]
A = pd.DataFrame({'a1': a1, 'a2': a2})
```

Now you have something like this:

```
  a1 a2
0  0  o
1  1  x
2  1  o
3  2  o
```

And you can add columns to it:

```
a3 = [0,0,1,1]
A['a3'] = a3
```

The first, unnamed column is the "index" so you can use it like this:

```
>>> print(A.loc[0])
0 o 0
```

You can also access specific columns:

```
>>> print(A['a3'])
0 0 1 1
```

This solution is much, much more efficient than lists of lists, and will offer much faster performance as your data grows.  For example you can sum an entire column very quickly with `A['a1'].sum()`, or add columns with `A['a1'] + A['a3']` (gives `0 1 2 3`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple method of expanding A in place:

For each new list, replace `a3` with the list name in this expression and run it:

```
A = [A[i] + (a3[i],) for i in range(len(a3))]
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
a1=[0,1,1,2]
a2=['o','x','o','o']
a3=[0,0,1,1]

def adjoin(*lists):
    return [i for i in zip(*lists)]

# usage:
A= adjoin(a1,a2,a3)
# result: A -> [(0, '0', 0), (1, 'x', 0), (1, 'o', 1), (2, 'o', 1)]
```